# Помогите, пожалуйста, переписать предложение. Продемонстрируйте высокий стиль )

Tags: грамотная-речь

Начальный вариант:

Я считаю, что только грубая сила может воспрепятствовать тому факту, что Василий Иванович также принимает учение Марксизма, ибо логически опровергнуть это невозможно!

Обьяснение смысла:
 Смысл тут в том, что есть факт – Василий Иванович принимает учение марксизма, и автор считает, что логически это опровергнуть невозможно. Что только грубая физическая сила, приводимая здесь иронично, способна поколебать убежденность автора, основанную на логическом анализе.
**Контекст тут такой**, что есть спор касательно того, принимает ли Василий Иванович учение Маркса или нет. Есть ряд людей, которые разделяют данное мнение и ряд тех, кто не разделяет. Автор же считает, что с точки зрения логического анализа, неоспоримо, что Василий Иванович разделяет его.

Задача в том, чтобы изложить описанный смысл в одном предложении. Так как меня убедили, что начальный вариант кривой.

Comment: Предложение хоть куда, но смысл не прослеживается.

Comment: @shampar Смысл тут в том, что есть факт – Василий Иванович принимает теорию марксизма, и автор считает, что логически это опровергнуть невозможно. Что только грубая физическая сила, приводимая здесь иронично, способна поколебать убежденность автора, основанную на логическом анализе.

Comment: В комментарии-то лучше изложено. В вопросе — полная беда. А с теорией... может ещё, с теоремой... Или философия, или течение или учение: «Учение Маркса всесильно, потому что оно верно». Попросите (исправив вопрос) помочь отредактировать эту фразу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если перефразировать исходное предложение:

> Я считаю, что только физически можно препятствовать Василию Ивановичу
>   в его приверженности марксизму, ибо логически разубедить его
>   невозможно.

Если следовать комментарию:

> Только грубая сила помешала бы мне утверждать, что Василий Иванович
>   тоже привержен марксизму, ибо логически меня в этом не разубедить.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1 (начальный)

Я считаю, что только грубая сила может воспрепятствовать тому, что Василий Иванович разделяет учение Маркса, ибо логически поколебать (изменить) его убежденность невозможно!

Вариант 2 (исправленный)

Только грубая сила можно изменить мое убеждение в том, что Василий Иванович разделяет учение Маркса, ибо сделать это логически не получится.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Но смысл здесь несколько сложнее. Он описан в комментарии выше. Суть в том, что автор считает, что логический анализ не способен опровергнуть тот факт, что Василий Иванович принимает учение Маркса. И, в виде иронии, что только грубая сила может как-то повлиять на этот факт – Василий Иванович принимает учение Маркса. Все это желательно выразить в одном предложении. То есть речь не про убежденность самого Василия Ивановича, а про факт его принятия учения и мнение автора в отношении данного факта.

Comment: **Контекст тут такой**, что есть спор касательно того, принимает ли Василий Иванович учение Маркса или нет. Есть ряд людей, которые разделяют данное мнение и ряд тех, кто не разделяет. Автор же считает, что с точки зрения логического анализа, неоспоримо, что Василий Иванович принимает это учение.

Comment: Фамилия его Чапаев?

Comment: @Sharon Спасибо! Да, видимо по-русски иначе не скажешь :)

Comment: @Alex_ander Може быть и Чапаев )) Это несколько видоизмененное предложение. Начальный вариант включает специфическую терминологию, которая тут только помешала бы.